# No data returned when going to controller action

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In my webapplication there is a table with records. A user can view te details of a record by clicking on a button that leads to /Logging/Details/id and that renders a View with all the details of that record. Everything is fine so far.

When I copy the url /Logging/Details/id and paste that url in the address bar, there is no data returned. When I debug I see that the ID is passed but nothing is returned...

Any idea's on how or what this is causing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of using LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of using LEFT JOIN.